# tensorflow one of 20 parameter server is very slow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train DNN model using tensorflow, my script have two variables, one is dense feature and one is sparse feature, each minibatch will pull full dense feature and pull specified sparse feature using embedding_lookup_sparse, feedforward could only begin after sparse feature is ready. I run my script using 20 parameter servers and increasing worker count did not scale out. So I profiled my job using tensorflow timeline and found one of 20 parameter server is very slow compared to the other 19. there is not dependency between different part of all the trainable variables. I am not sure if there is any bug or any limitation issues like tensorflow can only queue 40 fan out requests, any idea to debug it? Thanks in advance.
[tensorflow timeline profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qwHG.png)

Comment: Which parameter server is it? (ie, the first shard or not). Also can you check network traffic and cpu to make sure they are all trying to transfer the same amount of data and do same amount of cpu work?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov different running has different slow parameter server,network traffic(5~10%) and cpu usage(20%) are far away from busy, and different parameter servers have almost the same network traffic.

Comment: Is there any config or tools to see exactly what tensorflow is doing? for example logging every event so I could check when and where the worker send requests to and receive responses from. I don't understanding tensorflow timeline tool very well, seems there is no explicit data flow between workers and servers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have exactly 2 variables, one is stored at PS0 and the other at PS1. The other 18 parameter servers are not doing anything. Please take a look at variable partitioning (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops/variable_partitioners_for_sharding), i.e. partition a large variable into small chunks and store them at separate parameter servers.

Comment: I used fixed size partitioner and i am sure two variables were both spitted into 20 parameter servers, from the timeline graph i attached, you could see that all the parameter servers are working, the problem is that there was always one parameter that was very slow. I ran three times, the slow part were 5,7, 19, not the same one.

Comment: Hmmm, I have not used the profiling tool you used before. From the graph, the difference is fairly small? 200ms vs. 140ms?  Am I reading the diagram correctly?

Comment: Not exactly, the bottom one is worker, other are ps. The 4th is the super slow parameter server, the graph indicates that it's amlost 60ms slower than other for both pulling dense parameters and pushing gradients, and for sparse part, i think it's even 100ms slower.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack way to log `Send/Recv` timings from `Timeline` object for each iteration, but it works pretty well in terms of analyzing JSON dumped data (compared to visualize it on `chrome://trace`).

The steps you have to perform are:

- download TensorFlow source and checkout a correct branch (r0.12 for example)
- modify the only place that calls `SetTimelineLabel` method inside `executor.cc`

  - instead of only recording non-transferable nodes, you want to record `Send/Recv` nodes also.
  - be careful to call `SetTimelineLabel` once inside `NodeDone` as it would set the text string of a node, which will be parsed later from a python script
- build TensorFlow from modified source
- modify model codes (for example, `inception_distributed_train.py`) with correct way of using `Timeline` and graph meta-data

Then you can run the training and retrieve JSON file once for each iteration! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions that were too big for a comment:

You can't see data transfer in timeline that's because the tracing of Send/Recv is currently turned off, some discussion here -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4809

In the latest version (nightly which is 5 days old or newer) you can turn on verbose logging by doing `export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1` and it shows second level timestamps (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2076#issuecomment-275451855) about higher granularity).

So with vlog perhaps you can use messages generated by this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0a4f5b6bda405814af59803829216762e030728d/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc#L1103) to see the times at which `Send` ops are generated.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I will try verbose logging.

Comment: btw, as of 3 hours ago, there's now microseconds included in timestamps, so if you want those, you must build from latest head