# Tensorflow network resource usage

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

To evaluate the quality of job placements in distributed TensorFlow, I want to obtain the total size in bytes of the data sent through the network during training.  This is in preparation for further work on the automatic job placement algorithm.  Network usage will measure data locality of the training, and is a proxy for training delays.

My plan is to simply record all the sizes of tensors input to _Send nodes, then output and display this in the python profiling Timeline.  I've read the related discussions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4809) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867993/tensorflow-one-of-20-parameter-server-is-very-slow) and believe this correct in principle.  The only concern is my experiments have shown that Send and Recv nodes are used for communication within a process in addition to inter-process communication - which appears different from what's described in the whitepaper: https://www.tensorflow.org/about/bib.

Are there any caveats to my approach, and is this a good approximation to the actual amount of network used? Also, is data transferred a worthwhile quantity to minimize for minimizing delays, coming from job placements?